# Pandas - How to offset all values with if it less than previous value on whole dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got dataframe as follows:

```
time | value
0       30
1       40
5       55
10      10
11      25
20      10
```

As value stored should only increment (but sometimes it's being resetted) I want to create an output like follows;

```
0       30
1       40
5       55
10      65   //offset 55
11      80   //offset 55
20      90   //offset 80
```

Any easy way to achieve it with pandas?

Comment: why the second one not offset for 65?

Comment: Because there was no reset for data (10 -> 25)